# Rails 5 combine dropdown with text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called **Color** with **name** for its column. I have another model called **Car** which have **make**, **model**, and **color_id** for its column.

When creating a new **Car**,I would like to have a dropdown listing all the colors and at the bottom, there is an 'Other' option. How can I make a text field appear if the user choses the 'Other' option so the user can input a new color?

Also, if the user selected 'Other' and entered the input 'Yellow', how do I input this new **Color** data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with simple JQuery.

In your `Controller`:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def new # it is up to you if you used another function
     @colors = Color.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}
     @colors += [['Other', -1]] # as there is no negative ID
  end
end
```

In your 'View':

```
# views/cars/new.html.erb
# the following line to the input 
select_tag :color, options_for_select(@colors) #check documentation of select tag for more usability (like default option...)
```

All you have to do now is to add input text field with disabled property, Give that input text field an `id` for example `id="otherColor"`, Disable it using JQuery or JavaScript, and make a new actionListner on `change` for the select (By giving select_tag additional param called 'id' you will be allowed to do this), Then check if he used the the other option make he allowed to enter input.

Don't worry if he choose another option than the 'others', disabled inputs are not sent with the request, So in your controller you have to check if he sent you `params['otherColor']` if it is the case, Create new Color and attach it to the car, else attach the selected color from the dropdown list to the car, Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

A nice way to do this is with `datalists`

```
<datalist id='colors'>
  <% Color.all.each do |color| %>
    <option><%= color.name %></option>
  <% end %>
</datalist>

<input class='form-control' list='colors' id='car_color_name' name='car[color_name]' value='<%=@car.color.name%>'>
```

This gives you a pull-down input box where you can select any existing color by typing in the initial letters, or you can enter a completely new color into the same input box.

In your create and update method in cars_controller, you can do...

```
@car.color = Color.find_or_create_by(name: params[:car][:color_name])
```

No javascript needed!